# How to secure URL parameters in java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Sample URL http://dineshlingam.appspot.com/guestbook?name=xxx&skills=zzz

Sample Code

```
public class GuestbookServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException 
    {
        String userName = req.getParameter("name");
        String userSkills = req.getParameter("skills");
        if(userName != null && userSkills != null)
        {
            res.setContentType("text/plain");
            res.getWriter().println("Name : " + userName + ", Skills : " + userSkills);
        }
        else
            res.sendRedirect(req.getRequestURI());
    }
}
```

I am manually enter this URL to web browser.

How to secure parameters value.

Give me any one suitable example. Because I don't know the java concept and google-app-engine concept.

Really I don't know the SSL. So please I need detailed explanation of SSL with Example.

I am using eclipse to develop my application. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: +1 @Nishant Regular HTTP calls are not secure(GET, POST etc). HTTPS is the way to go.

Comment: This is my URl `localhost:8888/guestbook?name=xxx&skills=zzz`. How to add https.

Comment: HTTPS GET calls will still show up in server logs with the full url in most cases. HTTPS POST requests are usually the best way to go.

Comment: @danielbeard server logs does not imply that it is a network security flaw. You can always control server logs.

Comment: @Ck I am using eclipse to develop java application. Where I am added SSL. How to add SSL to my program. Give me sample code. Thanks.

Comment: @DineshLingam do you want to hide the parameters or do you want to secure network channel between client and server?

Comment: @DineshLingam if you use post method. your url becomes http://dineshlingam.appspot.com/guestbook. the parameters can not be seen by users. however, the parameters are send to user insecurely meaning they are not encrypted. therefore you can add a self signed certificate to your tomcat server to encrypt the parameters.

Comment: @Ck- Generally yes, although if the user is connecting through a proxy that doesn't belong to you it may become a problem however, that is probably outside the scope of this discussion.

Comment: You're going to have to clarify what you mean by 'secure'. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a classic example of a page vunerable to a CSS (Cross-Site-Scripting) attack. Using HTTPS wont mitigate that. Instead you need to escape any input before adding it to the page.

For example by using [`StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) and `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript()` from the Apache Commons Lang library.

Comment: Possibly the user entering the detail will follow the flow, but yes in other cases it may cause issue.

Comment: Please Explain I don't know that concept.

Comment: SSL(https) is server side configuration. Example [set this up for tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) If you are using something else, you would need to refer the documentation.

Comment: I am using eclipse to develop java application. Where I am added SSL. How to add SSL to my program. Give me sample code. Thanks.

Comment: @dineshlingam SSL is configuration and is NOT part of coding. You would need to configure container/Application server at the deployment end. You don't necessarily require to set it on development box.

Answer (score 1):

Using https does not secure url parameter by any mean. You have to put parameters either in header or body if you want to make it secure. However if you are making a call directly from browser for this you cant put it in header neither in body because it is a a GET request. +1 to nfechner for highlighting XSS issue in your code.

For your problem here are the possible workaround with https:

- Instead of GEt call use a POST call by putting this search in separate form in your page and use HTTPS on top of that.
- If you want to use GET request you have to put the parameters in Headers, make a search page, When user hits the search button, make ajax call to above resource by passing it into header using https call.